# Scrolling a Window of another application programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, scroll

I have been trying to fathom this out for most of this evening and have hit a brick wall. I am trying to identify the way how I can scroll an external application window by a specific amount of pixels and at each interval take a screenshot of the client area.  For instance when in Firefox I would like to be able to press a button in my WPF app and have it scrolled the firefox window client area by 200 pixels.

I have had some success scrolling down the window by sending messages to the handle of the window, however I want to do this in predefined chunks so that I can ultimately take a screenshot of the window each time the client area is scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: I'm confused. Your title says you want to scroll your WPF app, but your example says you want to click a button in your WPF app to cause some other app (FireFox) to scroll around. Which is it?

Comment: I guess I explained it badly. I am looking to progromatically scroll an external application by a specific amount and at each interval take a screenshot of the client area.